# Enable users to upload files to folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I am running Windows Server 2012, IIS 8, and ASP.NET 4.5.  Please be patient with me as I am new to both IIS and ASP.NET.

I am trying to build a site where users are able to upload multiple files which are placed into a folder hosted on the web server.  When the user clicks the "Upload" button, I want that page to refresh and a message "Your file is successfully uploaded" is displayed.

Here is some code/pseudocode:

**upload.aspx**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript">
            function validate() 
            {
                //does some validation stuff
                doUpload();
            }

            function doUpload() 
            {
                document.upload.todo.value="upload";
                document.upload.submit();
                //display message
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <p name="message" style="display:hidden">File successfully uploaded.</p>

    <form method="post" action="upload.aspx" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile1">
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile2">
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile3">
        ...
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Upload" onClick="return validate()">
    </form>
</html>
```

The code does not place the files into a folder yet and I am not sure how to go about specifying that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to struggle to do that with client side script.

This MSDN article explains the ASP.NET FileUpload control, have a read - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295177.aspx

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll look into the FileUpload control and the subsequent code-behind that is needed.  Thank you.